# Get multiple connection strings from web.config

Tags: c#, web-config, connection-string

How to get all the connection strings's names from the web.config via code in C#?

I tried this:

```
System.Configuration.Configuration webConfig = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
ConnectionStringsSection x = webConfig.ConnectionStrings;
string here = x.SectionInformation.Name;
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
    foreach (ConnectionStringSettings c in System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings)
    {
        //use c.Name
    }
```

Comment: You can read more about `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings` at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.connectionstringsettingscollection.aspx).

Comment: Get ***connection string*** from ***machine.config*** too. Not only ***web.config***.

Answer (score 7):

This is how to use LINQ to get list of connection string names:

```
List<string> names = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings
    .Cast<ConnectionStringSettings>()
    .Select(v => v.Name)
    .ToList();
```

Or you can build a dictionary of it:

```
Dictionary<string/*name*/, string/*connectionString*/> keyValue = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings
    .Cast<ConnectionStringSettings>()
    .ToDictionary(v => v.Name, v => v.ConnectionString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not specific to Connection Strings, but might be helpful none the less.

```
System.Web.HttpContext ctx = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;

Configuration config;

if (ctx != null)
    config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(ctx.Request.ApplicationPath);
```